# Dict_values' object does not support indexing

Tags: python, linguistics

The following is my code:

```
word_centroid_map =dict(zip(model.index2word, idx ))
for cluster in range(0,10):

# Print the cluster number  
print ("\nCluster %d" % cluster)

# Find all of the words for that cluster number, and print them out
words = []
for i in range(0,len(word_centroid_map.values())):
    if( word_centroid_map.values()[i] == cluster ):
        words.append(word_centroid_map.keys()[i])
print (words)
```

I am using python 3 and I am getting an error saying:

```
TypeError: 'dict_values' object does not support indexing
```

Can someone please help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to run (horribly inefficient) Python 2 code on Python 3.

Comment: If you have to search through values to get keys of interest, it can be a sign that your dict is keyed the wrong way.

Answer (score 2):

In python3.x, `dict.values()` doesn't return a list anymore -- it returns a `dict_values` object.  You can't subscript dict_values instances.  e.g.

```
dict_values = some_dict.values()
dict_values[any_value]  # TypeError!
```

In this case, it looks like the fix should be to stop using the indices and just iterate directly over the dictionary's *items*:

```
words = []
for key, item in word_centroid_map.items():
    if item == cluster:
        words.append(key)
print (words)
```

Or, as a list-comprehension:

```
words = [k for k, w in word_centroid_map.items() if w == cluster]
```

---

<sup>Also note that this should be *much* more efficient than the corresponding python2.x code (in which you're repeatedly generating lists to simply throw them away and re-generate on the next turn of the loop).</sup>

Comment: Nah, you're appending values.  He's appending keys.

Comment: @wim -- thanks, I missed that.  Luckily it's an easy fix :-)

Answer (score 1):

As addition/clarification to mgilson answer:

> The objects returned by dict.keys(), dict.values() and dict.items()
>   are view objects. They provide a dynamic view on the dictionary’s
>   entries, which means that when the dictionary changes, the view
>   reflects these changes.
>   (https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping)

Answer (score 1):

You can use also convert dict_values, dict_keys objects to list using `list()`:

```
list( word_centroid_map.keys() )[i]
```